# jquery cloning specify input items doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-clone

My goal is there is clone button inside the input section, when i click it clone the whole section including the input value which just inputed via jquery.

```
<section class='sectionContent'>
<button onClick="clone_section(this)"></button>
<input type="text" name="someinput">
<input type="text" name="someinput">
<input type="text" name="someinput">
<input type="text" name="someinput">
<input type="text" name="someinput">
<input type="text" name="someinput">
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clone_section(this) {
        console.log($(this).find("input"));
    }
</script>
```

when I console log inside the function it gives me different stuff from i directly console like

```
console.log('.sectionContent').find('input');
```

I am trying to do is fetch all the input value out and .clone() the whole section then put all the input value inside the new section.

Does anyone come with some better idea? please advise, thank you very much!

Comment: maybe try `$(this).nextAll("input")` Notice that none of your inputs are inside the button, so when you are using `.find()` on the button you are searching for inputs inside the button

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clearly state that I might have unlimited sections, section1, section2... section n, so whatever section I clone, will copy the content inside to a new section. So I don't think Next or Prev might be fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use `.nextAll("input")` or `$(obj).parent().find("input")`

Please note that `this`, is a reserved word, so use the following:

```
function clone_section(obj) {
  console.log($(obj).nextAll("input"));
}
```

**demo**

```js
function clone_section(obj) {
  console.log($(obj).nextAll("input"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class='sectionContent'>
  <button onClick="clone_section(this)"></button>
  <input type="text" name="someinput">
  <input type="text" name="someinput">
  <input type="text" name="someinput">
  <input type="text" name="someinput">
  <input type="text" name="someinput">
  <input type="text" name="someinput">
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the reserved word this in the function as a var:

```
function clone_section(theChosen) {
  console.log($(theChosen).find("input"));
}
```

However the button does not have inputs - you likely meant

```js
$(".sectionContent>button").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // or have type="button"
  console.log($(this).closest("section").find("input"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class='sectionContent'>
  <button>Click</button><br/>
  <input type="text" name="someinput"><br/>
  <input type="text" name="someinput"><br/>
  <input type="text" name="someinput"><br/>
  <input type="text" name="someinput"><br/>
  <input type="text" name="someinput"><br/>
  <input type="text" name="someinput"><br/>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Extended the answer of **mplungjan** a bit.

```js
$(".sectionContent>button").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // or have type="button"
  $(this).closest("section").find( 'input' ).clone().appendTo( $('.clonesHere') );
  $('<hr>').appendTo( $('.clonesHere') ); // just for visuals
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class='sectionContent'>
  <button>Click</button><br/>
  <input type="text" name="someinput"><br/>
  <input type="text" name="someinput"><br/>
  <input type="text" name="someinput"><br/>
  <input type="text" name="someinput"><br/>
  <input type="text" name="someinput"><br/>
  <input type="text" name="someinput"><br/>
</section>

Clones here:
<section class='clonesHere'></section>
```